# Client for Checkpoint Endpoint Security VPN

Tags: vpn

In windows, I use a client called "Checkpoint Endpoint Security", with an certificate file, in order to connect to the Checkpoint VPN.

Is there a compatible solution for Ubuntu?

Comment: Have a look in this topic on serverfault: http://serverfault.com/questions/90275/checkpoint-vpn-linux-client

Comment: Have you solved your Checkpoint VPN problem yet? (6 years later)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix nope, I apologize. But probably today there are different clients, and maybe even official Ubuntu support.

Comment: @ElazarLeibovich No need to apologize for technology :D Does these mean we can close the question as non reproducible?